# Linux Execution Permission Denied Although I'm permitted to execute

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

I have a file on Linux system whose permissions are as the following: --wx--x--x. I applied the chmod 311 command to the file basically. Even though as a user I'm allowed to execute it, I cannot execute the file. What can be the reason for this?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have SE linux? what do you mean by "cannot execute it" where does the error comes from?

Comment: If that file is a script then you need both read and execute permissions.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thank you. yes it's a script. I've just figured out before you wrote :)

Comment: Change it to `755` instead of `311`; you can't execute a script without having reading rights